# Sharepoint database connection issue after upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint

I took a backup of all our Sharepoint WSS 3.0 databases and restored them to a new Windows 2008 R2 server.

The new SQL server has the same name and IP address as the old one.  The only difference between the two is the new one has SQL 2008 R2 and the old one has SQL 2005.

When I navigate to the sharepoint url I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to the configuration database.
```

I checked the logs at this location: "%commonprogramfiles%/Microsoft Shared/web server extensions/12/Logs" and found this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted
domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this article?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your SharePoint farm might be trying to connect via SQL Authentication and the SQL Server isn't setup to accept SQL Authentication.